# Gatling tool turn off timeout exception

Tags: web-services, http, exception, testing, gatling

Can you tell me how to change or turn off timeout in simulation?
I think about this exception:

> 19:27:49.951 [WARN ] c.e.e.g.h.a.GatlingAsyncHandler - Request 'long
>   request' failed java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: No response
>   received after 60000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See related documentation here: https://github.com/excilys/gatling/wiki/Configuration#wiki-config-files

Comment: this link to documentation does not exist any longer.